# Texmaker: How to "type through" closing brackets, braces, and parentheses?

Tags: texmaker, braces, auto-completion

I'll start by saying that my recent experiences using Python 3.3 (a programming language) have prompted me to question the potential of my favorite way to "TeX" something using Texmaker.

In Python, when you define a function or simply create a left parenthesis\bracket\brace (hereafter collectively described by the word "brace"), the cursor moves immediately past the left brace and creates a corresponding right brace following the cursor. The convenient feature of Python is that when I'm done typing the argument of the braces, all I have to do to "escape" the inner part of the braces is to simply re-type the automatically-created right brace. As soon as the cursor advances past the right brace, the left brace, the right brace, and everything within the argument maintains a temporary gray-fill background to help the user verify that the argument is correct.

I love this feature of Python and Texmaker is certainly almost as good for typing commands for environments. Texmaker has its own way of indicating where the argument begins and ends by highlighting the left and right braces in yellow and also changing the font color of those braces to red on my system. The problem I am having is that in Texmaker I cannot "type through" the automatically-created right braces; such an ability would be most helpful because Texmaker uses braces so often.

I'll do my best to illustrate what I'm looking for below and then what the problem looks like. If you can allow the vertical bar "|" to represent the cursor, the following happens:

Let's say I'm almost done typing the fraction of 1/2 in the simplest format (note that the auto-complete feature is what created all 4 of the braces when I began to type `\frac`.

---

This is what I'm looking for:

`\frac{1}{2|}`        (Just finished typing `2`, Cursor is behind the `2`, I now want to "type through" the rightmost brace.

`\frac{1}{2}|`        (I have just typed `}` and the cursor can continue typing. This is what I want to be able to do.)

This is what Texmaker does for me:

`\frac{1}{2}|}`        (I have just typed `}` and the cursor is between 2 right braces. Thus, a mismatched brace is created and I have to press DELETE to continue typing as before.

So my formal question is: With Texmaker's auto-complete feature enabled, how can "type through" (as demonstrated above) the closing brace at the end of an argument? Any help is extremely appreciated!

Comment: There is no relationship between LaTeX and python. To insert \frac, just use the auto-completion \frac{•}{•} (or the keyboard shortcut or the corresponding button in the toolbar) and the tab key to go directly to the next placeholder •.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: That is not a feature of *Python* I think, but rather a feature of whatever editor you use to write Python.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Thanks for the starter page link.

Comment: I understand there is no relationship between LaTeX and Python. I just think the feature of typing through automatically-created braces is extremely convenient in Python and I don't know how to do it in Texmaker. I apologize for not specifying which editor I use: I've been using Eclipse now for about 7 months. Unfortunately, due to some other problems, I can't open Eclipse anymore and describe what Options I changed to get the result of my above example, but in Texmaker.

Comment: Again, that feature has *nothing* to do with Python. If you're willing to try another editor, take a look at [TeXstudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net) which is a fork of Texmaker. It does this.

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour you describe has nothing to with the Python programming language, it is a feature of the editor you use to write the Python code -- Eclipse, as I understand it.

If Texmaker doesn't do this, then you can't really do anything other than [file a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/list) and see if the author adds it, or learn to live without it.

The other option is to switch to a different LaTeX-editor, of which there are many, see [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides). For example, Eclipse has a LaTeX plugin called TeXlipse, so I assume this does what you want as well. Another suggestion is a fork of Texmaker called [TeXstudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/) which has this feature.