# Is there a quick way to jump out of brackets in TexMaker?

Tags: texmaker, brackets

This might sound like a minor issue, but I love typing in Latex and its shortcuts in e.g. Texmaker are awesome, like when I want to type `\frac{}{}`, I can use auto-completion and jump between brackets with .

But is there a way, other than moving the cursor with either Right or Ctrl+Right, to GET OUT of brackets?

Because now, my hands can stay in a steady position all the time, except when I want to exit brackets of all kinds, than I have to move to the weird position, which is to hit the right arrow key to get out of brackets?

So, is there some feature like that? where I for example type `\frac`, hit TAB to autocomplete to `\frac{}{}`, then hit TAB to jump into the first bracket, type something, hit TAB to jump to the next bracket, type something and then hit `<Whatever>` to jump out of the last bracket?

Does anyone know an editor, who has functionality like that, other than using arrow keys? Thanks in advance :)

---

Update:
My personal work-around right now is to use the "custom completion" option in the user menu, there you can define your own placeholders with "@", and simply put one of those behind the last bracket in, for example, a fraction.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Emacs does :) Emacs treats brace groups as lists, so the list navigation functionality works as you'd expect.  I have them bound to `Ctrl+(Up|Down|Left|Right)` respectively.

Comment: I think it can be done using TeXmaker with `TAB` key except that it might difficult to exit from last pair of braces

Comment: That's what I mean, it's perfect, except for the last pair of braces, and I haven't found a good solution yet unfortunately!

Comment: @MartinWinter may be post a comment or star this enhancement feature at texmaker bug tracker https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/detail?id=1138&can=1&q=exit&colspec=ID%20Type%20Summary

Comment: thanks @texenthusiast, I commented too but now I at least have a work-around, simply change the most used "custom completions" and I'm a lot faster now!

Comment: TeXstudio is based on TeXmaker and you can edit all shortcuts.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is an open IDE issue unrelated to TeX see https://code.google.com/archive/p/texmaker/issues/1138 see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130331/texmaker-how-to-type-through-closing-brackets-braces-and-parentheses

Answer (score 2):

I have just found a workaround for **Linux**:

1. install [autokey](https://code.google.com/p/autokey/) (for GUI versions use autokey-gtk or autokey-qt respectively)
2. add new sample script

   ```
   keyboard.send_key("<end>")
   keyboard.send_key("<enter>")
   ```
3. assign it some hotkey you wish to use, I used `Ctrl+j`
4. [optionally] set a window filter for the Texmaker on the bottom of the script window: `Set > Detect Window Properties > Click on the TexMaker title bar > OK (entire class)`
5. save, make the AutoKey run (if it is running not already)

Now, in TexMaker you can press Ctrl+j to jump to the next line, from wherever you are, without moving anything and without the need for cursor keys.

Note that the similar procedure could in theory be applied to AutoHotKey for Windows, and I am almost sure it is possible, but since I have not used Windows for a long time, I cannot provide the exact guide. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I just found out by chance that I can use `<ctrl> + <e>` in my TeXMaker 4.41 on Ubuntu to jump to the end of the line, which does the job to jump out of the brackets as well.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!  It doesn't work for me Texmaker 4.5.