# Jump out of brackets in TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio, brackets, auto-completion

I have a question very similar to [Is there a quick way to jump out of brackets in TexMaker?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/202383/is-there-a-quick-way-to-jump-out-of-brackets-in-texmaker) but regarding TeXStudio. When I open some kind of bracket (any kind), TeXstudio automatically adds corresponding closing bracket in a small black box, see the picture.

[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [schurov.com](http://schurov.com/images/texstudio-brackets.png))</sub>

I want to write something in the brackets and then press a hotkey to jump out of the brackets (i.e. place the cursor after the closing bracket). I believe that the black box suggests that it is possible because it is visually similar to the black box around a placeholder. However, the usual hotkey used to go to the next placeholder doesn't work. `Edit → Go To → Next mark` doesn't work either.

Personally, I'm ok to press `→` two times, but that black boxes around the closing brackets are annoying.

It seems to be something very simple but I didn't find answer in the docs or google, really.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's really as simple as typing `)`.

There's also `Idefix -> Remove Placeholders` (Ctrl+Shift+K).

Comment: What about jumping out of curly braces? It seems that type `}` does not work!